# Why is expectation of a exponential family equal to $\frac{\partial A(\eta)}{\partial \eta}$?

Tags: statistics

My understanding: A member of the exponential family is any well defined distribution of the form $h(x)\exp[\eta \boldsymbol{\cdot} T(x)-A(\eta)]$ where $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ ,  $A:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and $h:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ are arbitrary functions.

[image]

[image]

The above used moment generating function to prove the last property in quesion. But I am not sure why the integral equals the $e^{A(\eta+u)-A(\eta)}$. Are there more conditions on the function A H ,and T that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the density must have integral equal to one, we have
$$\int h(x) e^{\eta^\top T(x) - A(\eta)} \, dx = 1$$
$$\implies e^{A(\eta)} = \int h(x) e^{\eta^\top T(x)} \, dx.$$

Then just plug in $\eta + u$ into $A(\cdot)$ to verify your expression.